# Python django cannot import name views

Tags: python, django

Ive setup django and am setting up my urls like

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
 from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^home/$', views.homepage),
]
```

The above always produces an error

```
cannot import name views
```

PROJECT STRUCTURE

```
geoff
   settings.py
   urls.py  //using this
   wsgi.py

 homepage
   migrations->folder
   _init_.py
   .....others here
   views.py
```

Comment: show your project structure for better understanding

Comment: this is main URL file... in main project folder. || Go to app folder and create urls.py and import the same. || from . import something means you should have the something file in the same directory.

Comment: use this  `from __future__ import absolute_import` hope this solved your issue

Comment: @Kalariya_M ive updated the question with project structure

Comment: @ShivShankar am doing that in the urls.py

Comment: @ManojJadhav still doesnt solve it

Comment: You have a `homepage` directory where `views.py` is located, in which case you need to do `from homepage import views`.

Comment: @solarissmoke  then how do i map it to the url part

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... If you import views, you can now just refer to the specific view method/class in your URL configuration.

Comment: what i mean isi have other apps like about us , Now in my url when i say from homepage import views, from aboutus import views  then in my url config  url(r'^home/$', view), url(r'^aboutus/$', views), this will not work.

Comment: @solarissmoke am still new to python django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
from homepage import views
```

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI you include it the same way

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI if you have differents views.py you can use different import name like example `from homepage import views as views1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `from . import views` to `from homepage.views import homepage(mapping function)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a indent issue in your urls.py.

Check the below line

```
`from . import views`
```

You have a extra space at start of this line. Please remove the space your problem will gets solved.